# getting NaN on multiplication of 2no. jsp

Tags: jsp, nan

I want to multiply value of 2 textbox and display on 3rd textbox
I tried these coding in javascript but not getting proper m getting NaN

```
function cal()
{
   var as1=document.getElementById("sa").value;  
   var not1= parseInt(document.getElementById("not").value);
   var rs1= parseInt(document.getElementById("r1").value);
    if(as1>=not1)
    {
        if(document.getElementById('r1').checked)
        {
          var c= rs1*not1;
          document.getElementById("ta").value= c;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. "as1" should be "rs1", right?

Comment: have a look into your javascript console. In which line does it complain about NaN? can be multiple sources here as there are multiple elements that may contain numbers - or no number.